# insert row in a specific position

Tags: excel, vba

I have this sub that insert a new row into an excel sheet. 
Each row has a date in column A and I want to keep the date in order (from oldest to newest) inserting. So if the date I want to insert is greater than the last date I just add a new row at the bottom.
Otherwise I look for the point where to insert a blank row and populate the data.
I'm stuck on the part where I insert the new row:

```
cell.Rows(riga).EntireRow.insert
```

The whole sub is this:

```
Sub insert_row()
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    data_last = Range("A" & lastRow).Value

    'prendo i valori
    data_mov = new_mov.data.Value
    descr_mov = new_mov.descr.Value
    importo_mov = new_mov.importo.Value

    'emetto un alert se la data inserita minore di quella della riga precedente (lastRow)
    If data_mov < data_last Then
        MsgBox "movimento nel passato"
        Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
        Set rng = Range("C5:C" & lastRow)
        For Each cell In rng
            riga = cell.Row
            data = Range("A" & riga).Value
            If data > data_mov Then
                riga = riga - 1
                cell.Rows(riga).EntireRow.insert
                Exit For
            End If
            Next cell

    Else
        'li inserisco nella prima riga vuota sotto
        nxt_row = lastRow + 1
        Range("A" & nxt_row).Value = data_mov
        Range("B" & nxt_row).Value = descr_mov
        Range("C" & nxt_row).Value = CDbl(importo_mov)
        Call Saldo_upd
    End If
    'evidenzio una cella di quella riga



    'ricalcolo il saldo

End Sub
```

I don't get any error message and nothing happens. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a cell reference and you want to insert a row before it is cell.EntireRow.Insert` similar to:

```
dim cell as range
set cell = Range("A2")
cell.EntireRow.Insert
```

...or if you want to insert before Row 3:

```
Rows(3).EntireRow.Insert
```

...or a insert a number of rows:

```
Rows("3:8").EntireRow.Insert
```

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**`Range.EntireRow` Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-entirerow-property-excel)
- MSDN : [**`Range.Insert` Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-insert-method-excel)